# Objective-C int convert to UTF-8

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, utf-8

I want to convert this int num: `53392` to cyrillic letter `A`. I use this: `NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 53392];` But this now work properly and return me strange symbols. Can someone help me?

Comment: 53392 written in hex is 0xD090. "D0 90" is the UTF-8 representation of CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A, but usually UTF-8 is stored as sequence of bytes and not stored in an integer like this. - How do you obtain that number?

Comment: Do you want to output any UTF-8 encoded character? Or do you just want CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A?

Comment: While `d0 90` are the UTF-8 bytes for U+0410, it is not the same as the number 53392.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `%C` format (capital letter C). Second, code for cyrillic A is 0x0410, not your number.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to create NSString that contains unicode characters is to use stringWithUTF8String and the \u#### escape sequence, like this:

```
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"To be continued\u2026"];
```

Comment: With this: `NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"To be continued\u53392"];` output is 匹2

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode - just use unicode insead of some hex number \u0421

Answer (score 0):

The integer you have, 53392, is the two bytes 0xD0 and 0x90 packed into an integer, which are the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode 0x410 (decimal 1040) cyrillic capital A.

There are multiple ways to do your conversion, here are two.

If you know the UTF-8 sequence (which you can extract out of the integer if needed) you can convert it to an `NSString` using a sequence like:

```
char buf[2];
buf[0] = 0xD0;
buf[1] = 0x90;
NSString *cyrillicA = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buf length:2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If you know the UTF-16 value you can use the %C format:

```
NSString *cyrillicA = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x410];
```